# Multiple imputation with additive constraint

Tags: multiple-imputation

Say I have a dataset which includes three binary (dichotomous) variables: A, B, C, and C takes the value of A OR B. Many observations have missing A and B, and non-missing C.

I guess that C should be included in any multiple imputation model, since it contains valuable information. But is there any multiple imputation package (preferably in R) giving the ability to specify the relation C = A OR B, so that only sensible values (satisfying the relation) are imputed?

Thanks in advance!